pandera: how to create a DataFrameSchema or DataFrameModel from existing pandas.DataFrame?
I have written a data transformation function that eats a pandas.DataFrame at input and returns another pandas.DataFrame at ouput. I have a reference pandas.DataFrame object on which I was testing my function.
I want to check input data schema to make sure that the schema of input dataframe is always the same as it was in my reference dataframe.
I've found out that there is pandera library that is intended to automate such checks: just write a DataFrameSchema or DataFrameModel and have fun.
But I don't want to write my DataFrameModel manually. Can I somehow generate it from existing dataframe?

What about just inferring the schema
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'C': [True, False, True]
})

schema = pa.infer_schema(df)

print(schema)


which is
<Schema DataFrameSchema(
    columns={
        'A': <Schema Column(name=A, type=DataType(int64))>
        'B': <Schema Column(name=B, type=DataType(object))>
        'C': <Schema Column(name=C, type=DataType(bool))>
    },
    checks=[],
    coerce=True,
    dtype=None,
    index=<Schema Index(name=None, type=DataType(int64))>,
    strict=False,
    name=None,
    ordered=False,
    unique_column_names=False,
    metadata=None, 
    add_missing_columns=False
)>

